# Convert a time (MM:SS) to a float (of seconds) before POST/PUT to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want a user to be able to select or enter a time (ex: "how long do you spend brushing your teeth in the morning?") and on the 'CREATE' or 'UPDATE' actions, I would like to convert the time to a float of seconds before the post/put to the database.

I have the methods in a module right now (trying to learn how to use modules), but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for this situation...

Float-to-Time for View (works)

```
<%= MyModule.float_to_time(task.task_length) %>
```

**Module**

```
module MyModule

  def self.float_to_time(secs)       # task.task_length (view)
     ...
     ...
  end

  def self.time_to_float(tim)        # :task_length (controller)
     m = tim.strftime("%M").to_f
     s = tim.strftime("%S.%2N").to_f
     t = ((m*60) + s)
     return t.round(2)
  end

end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
  # "time_to_float" (Convert task_time to seconds float)
  # Create new task after conversion
  @task = Task.new(params[:task])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

---

How do I do the conversion before the post (or put) to the db?

Also, should I move these methods to the application_controller, or is my module ok?

-- Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't forget that `//` does not begin a comment in Ruby. `#` does. You might want to edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: Whoops, brain fart. Thanks Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this seems like a job for the model, not for the controller. The model should be concerned with how the data is stored and converting data types as appropriate.

Since you're trying to learn how to use modules, you could keep those methods in a module as instance methods and mix them into your model class:

```
module TimeConversions
  def time_to_float(time)
    # ...
  end

  def float_to_time(seconds)
    # ...
  end
end

class Task
  extend TimeConversions
  before_save :convert_length

  # ...

private

  def convert_length
    self.length = self.class.time_to_float(length) if length.to_s.include?(':')
  end
end
```

Then you could still use `float_to_time` in the views:

```
<%= Task.float_to_time(task.length) %>
```

You would probably do something more sophisticated in your `before_save` filter, but maybe this will give you some ideas.

Comment: Couldn't ask for more. Thanks Brandan.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an [ActiveRecord Callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

In this, case you could have something like:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :convert_task_length_to_float

  def convert_task_length_to_float
    # do the conversion. set `self.task_float =` to update the value that will be saved
  end
end
```

The `before_save` callback will call before the `Task` is saved into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could override setter and getter for task_length accessor. Like this (in Task model):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  def task_length=(tim)
    m = tim.strftime("%M").to_f
    s = tim.strftime("%S.%2N").to_f
    t = ((m*60) + s)
    write_attribute(:task_length, t.round(2))
  end

  def task_length_to_time
    tl = read_attribute(:task_length)
    # ... float-to-time stuff
  end
end
```

And then use it in view `<%= task.task_length_to_time %>`. And use `task.task_length` if you need it in float.